# Using sample() from within Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I have a matrix containing probabilities, with each of the four columns corresponding to a score (an integer in sequence from 0 to 4). I want to sample a single score for each row using the probabilities contained in that row as sampling weights. In rows where some columns do not contain probabilities (NAs instead), the sampling frame is limited to the columns (and their corresponding scores) which do (e.g. for a row with 0.45,0.55,NA,NA, either 0 or 1 would be sampled). However, I get this error (followed by several others), so how can I make it work?:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'as<Rcpp::IntegerVector>(Rcpp::Matrix<14>::Sub&)'
     score[i] = sample(scrs,1,true,as<IntegerVector>(probs));
```

Existing answers suggest RcppArmadillo is the solution but I can't get that to work either. If I add:
`require(RcppArmadillo)`
before the cppFunction and
`score[i] = Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(scrs,1,true,probs);`
in place of the existing sample() statement, I get:

```
error: 'Rcpp::RcppArmadillo' has not been declared
     score[i] = Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(scrs,1,true,probs);
```

Or if I also include,
`#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>`
at the top, I get:

```
fatal error: RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h: No such file or directory
   #include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
```

Reproducible code:

```
p.vals <- matrix(c(0.44892077,0.55107923,NA,NA,
                 0.37111195,0.62888805,NA,NA,
                 0.04461714,0.47764478,0.303590351,1.741477e-01,
                 0.91741642,0.07968127,0.002826406,7.589714e-05,
                 0.69330800,0.24355559,0.058340934,4.795468e-03,
                 0.43516823,0.43483784,0.120895859,9.098067e-03,
                 0.73680809,0.22595438,0.037237525,NA,
                 0.89569365,0.10142719,0.002879163,NA),nrow=8,ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)

step.vals <- c(1,1,3,3,3,3,2,2)

require(Rcpp)
cppFunction('IntegerVector scores_cpp(NumericMatrix p, IntegerVector steps){

  int prows = p.nrow();

  IntegerVector score(prows);
  
  for(int i=0;i<prows;i++){
    int step = steps[i];
    
    IntegerVector scrs = seq(0,step);
    
    int start = 0;
    int end = step;
    
    NumericMatrix::Sub probs = p(Range(i,i),Range(start,end));

    score[i] = sample(scrs,1,true,probs);
  }
  
  return score;
  
}')

test <- scores_cpp(p.vals,step.vals)
test
```

Note: the value of step.vals for each row is always equal to the number of columns containing probabilities in that row -1. So passing the step.values to the function may be extraneous.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please try a search at the site here by entering the string (which its square brackets, ie all from inside the quotes) `'[rcpp] sample'` as this has been dsicussed a few times.  Also, try it in a package or at least via `sourceCpp()` -- there are limits to what `cppFunction()` (though it too has arguments for header includes you miss here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for the pointers. I also had some problems with indexing the matrix, so that part is changed, too. The following code works as intended (using `sourceCpp()`):

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

IntegerVector scores_cpp(NumericMatrix p, IntegerVector steps){
  
  int prows = p.nrow();
  
  IntegerVector score(prows);
  
  for(int i=0;i<prows;i++){
    int step = steps[i];
    
    IntegerVector scrs = seq(0,step);
    
    NumericMatrix probs = p(Range(i,i),Range(0,step));

    IntegerVector sc = RcppArmadillo::sample(scrs,1,true,probs);
    score[i] = sc[0];
  }
  
  return score;
  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be having a 'forest for the trees' moment here.  The `RcppArmadillo` unit tests actually provide a working example.  If you look at the source file [inst/tinytest/test_sample.R](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/tinytest/test_sample.R), it has a simple

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("cpp/sample.cpp")
```

and in the [that file inst/tinytest/cpp/sample.cpp](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/tinytest/cpp/sample.cpp) we have the standard

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
```

to a) tell R to look at `RcppArmadillo` header directories and b) include the sampler extensions.  This is how it works, and this has been documented to work for probably close to a decade.

As an example I can just do (in my `$HOME` directory containing `git/rcpparmadillo`)

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("git/rcpparmadillo/inst/tinytest/cpp/sample.cpp")
> set.seed(123)
> csample_integer(1:5, 10, TRUE, c(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.05))
 [1] 1 3 2 3 4 1 2 3 2 2
>
```

The later Rcpp addition works the same way, but I find working with parts of matrices to be more expressive and convenient with RcppArmadillo.

*Edit:* Even simpler for anybody with the `RcppArmadillo` package installed:

```
< library(Rcpp)
> sourceCpp(system.file("tinytest","cpp","sample.cpp", package="RcppArmadillo"))
> set.seed(123)
> csample_integer(1:5, 10, TRUE, c(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.05, 0.05))
 [1] 1 3 2 3 4 1 2 3 2 2
>
```